# space in url Django

Tags: python, css, django, windows, searchbar

I am creating a search bar on my site, everything is fine if I pass the names without spaces, being that I pass the word of the search bar directly in the url, as you can imagine the problem arises when the user enters words with space. I also convert the url into utf-8, but I think django does it automatically because even without the conversion in the url if you pass the space it appears at its post% 20, I wanted to clarify that the problem persists if you enter characters like:! ?can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from dac import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import re_path #include
from django.contrib import admin

app_name = 'dac'
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('doctors/<slug:slug>', views.doctor, name='doctors'),
    path('doctors/search/<slug:slug>/<slug:slug2>', views.doctor_search, name='doctors_search'),
    re_path(r'^doctors_search/search/(?P<slug>.)/(?P<slug2>\d+)$', views.doctor_search, name='doctors_search'),
    path('<slug:slug>', views.doctor_detail, name='doctor_detail'),
    path('signup/', views.sign_up, name="sign_up"),
    path('login/', views.log_in, name='log_in'),
    path('logout/', views.log_out, name='log_out'),
    path('reports/', views.reports, name='reports'),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

views.py:

```
def doctor(request, slug):
    print("slug: ",slug)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("slug: ",slug)
        risposta=request.POST.get("textAnswer")
        risposta=risposta.upper()

        risposta_list=risposta.rsplit()
        print(risposta_list)

        actual_url=request.build_absolute_uri()
        url=re.sub("\d+$", "search/%s/1"%(risposta), actual_url)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(url.encode('utf-8'))
        
    slug=int(slug)
    max_slug=int(round(doctors.objects.count()/28,0))

    if slug==1:
        prew_slug=slug
    else:
        prew_slug=slug-1

    if slug==max_slug:
        nxt_slug=max_slug
    else:
        nxt_slug=slug+1

    doc_list=doctors.objects.all()[(slug-1)*28:slug*28]
    {"doc_list":doc_list}

    return render(request, 'dac/doctors.html', locals())

def doctor_search(request, slug, slug2):
    slug2=int(slug2)
    print("slug1: ",slug)
    print("slug2: ",slug2)

    if request.method=="POST":
        risposta=request.POST.get("textAnswer")
        risposta=risposta.upper()

        actual_url=request.build_absolute_uri()
        url=actual_url.replace(slug, risposta)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(url.encode('utf-8'))

    slug=urllib.parse.unquote(slug)
    doc_list=doctors.objects.filter(frst_nm=slug) | doctors.objects.filter(lst_nm=slug) | doctors.objects.filter(pri_spec=slug)

    if doc_list.count()==0:
        messages.error(request, "no result")

    max_slug=int(round(doc_list.count()/28,0))
    
    if slug2==1:
        prew_slug=slug2
    else:
        prew_slug=slug2-1

    if slug2==max_slug:
        nxt_slug=max_slug
    else:
        nxt_slug=slug2+1
    doc_list=doc_list.all()[(slug2-1)*28:slug2*28]

    {"doc_list":doc_list}

    return render(request, 'dac/doctors_search.html', locals())
```

Let me explain better, when I visit the doctors page in which there is a search bar the doctor function is called, where if a word is entered and enter, the if condition occurs in the doctor function, which redirects to the url containing the word entered by the user, once redirected to the url: "search / 'answer' / 1 the doctor_search function is called in the view.py which takes the user's answer and the slug from the url, the problem arises when the user enters a word with space or special characters and django gives me 404 error

Comment: You didn't explain what the problem is. Yes, a space is encoded as %20 in an URL. Do you have any problems with that?

Comment: the problem is how to pass the word entered in the search bar in the url even if there are spaces, being that django gives me an error when entering spaces

Answer (score 0):

Use :

> <str:var>

instead of :

> <slug:var>

```
path('doctors/search/<str:slug>/<str:slug2>', views.doctor_search, name='doctors_search'),
```